# Sending Params in Drawer Navigation React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, navigation

Problem: send a flag to a component to make a conditional call to API

So i have two use case 
**first**: to Fetch Selective Data
**second**: to Fetch All Data

So i have used the same component in a Drawer Navigation and trying to pass a flag in the code like below

```
<Drawer.Navigator>
     <Drawer.Screen initialParams={{ showAll: false }} name="Selective Data" component={Dashboard} />
     <Drawer.Screen initialParams={{ showAll: true }} name="See All Data" component={Dashboard} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

But initialParams is only set once. But i want to signal the component to make separate API calls
to fetch data accordingly.

Using a [Drawer Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation) is must in my case.
How can i pass data.
 Any help is appreciated. much!

Comment: please share the code for Dashboard component

Comment: Lets assume its a basic React native component. I was needing ways to pass data to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the passed parameters using the route.params and do the processing accordingly, Below is a simple code to show the text based on the param.

```
function HomeScreen({ route,navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{route.params.showAll?"ALL":"Single"}</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen initialParams={{ showAll: false }} name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen initialParams={{ showAll: true }} name="Home1" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

You can check the snack for a demo
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/fbe120

Comment: ya i could do that. But use case was a bit different.